# One, two, and three weeks from now

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, computer-puzzle

I just came across this note in my office!

> Date of writing: Sept. 9th, 2015
>
> In exactly one week from today, and then a week from that date and then another week afterwards, something will happen that causes certain badly designed computer programs to function improperly on those days.
>
> It happens those three days and no other days in the year 2015. In any given year it will happen in exactly three days out of the year.

What might this finicky event be?

Comment: Exactly one week from today is my birthday! Is that just a red herring?

Comment: Yeah, that's got nothing to do with it.

Comment: The simplest answer is that it always happens on September 16, 23, and 30. But I'm guessing you've got an answer that's a little more exciting in mind?

Comment: Sorry if you dislike my edit, it was the easiest way I could put in the proper dates with adding meta information

Comment: Question: is it the same days each year? Or do they differ each year?

Comment: Questions: Do we need some country-specific knowledge or will it only happen in certain countries? Does the problem occur at a specific time, or all throughout the days?

Comment: The events are on different days each year, do not require any country specific knowledge (although the puzzle is in English), and occurs throughout the whole day.

Comment: Great puzzle +1, interesting problem with a satisfying solution.

Comment: The current answer does not satisfy the rule *In any given year it will happen in exactly three days out of the year.* What if I pick the year of 2025 for instance?

Comment: @warspyking Then it will happen on the 10th, 17th, and 24th.

Comment: @Joe Z. Woah! I miscounted! Lol

Comment: @warspyking: Since there are exactly 21 days with two digits in September, exactly three of them will occur on a Wednesday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> Every Wednesday in September with a double digit for the date. Programs writing out the date like "Wednesday September 16th, 2015" will have the longest print on these days because Wednesday and September have the most letters out of the days of the week and months of the year respectively. For the above example format, if the print buffer is a char[30], there will be a buffer overflow for these three days of the year.

---

**Old alternative answer**

Potential answer:

> if(strcmp(dayoftheweek,"Wednesday")==0 && (day==16||day==23||day==30) && monthoftheyear%2==1)destroyEverything();

Explanation:

> This line of code snuck in by a mischievous programmer would make any program fail three days of every year. Every year has two months where the Wednesdays fall on the 16th, 23rd, and the 30th, and they fall on even and odd months. Last year's occurred in July. (Note: leaving out platform-specific access of date information)

Comment: That's a bit too roundabout. The error I'm thinking of was an innocent error, not something deliberately contrived like that one.

Comment: I'll give you a hint, though: you're on the right track thinking about Wednesdays.

Comment: @JoeZ. I think your hint helped me find the intended answer.

Comment: Your answer is now correct. It's actually based off of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/169773/1840326) to an old, closed StackOverflow question. I posed it as a question to somebody, to guess what sort of bug they might have gotten with the date, and thought, hmm, this might make a good puzzle.

Comment: "Wednesday September 16th, 2015" is exactly 30 characters long. So why would there be a buffer overflow for char[30]? *I am not a very good programmer, so I cannot understand your reasoning.*

Comment: @CodeNewbie C strings have a null byte to indicate the end of the string.

Comment: @isaacg: Thank you! TIL something interesting and useful.

Comment: @CodeNewbie TIL what TIL stands for!